# Access 2010 SQL UPDATE with JOIN Missing Operator

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run an UPDATE query in MS Access 2010, using a JOIN but I repeatedly get a 'Missing Operator in Expression' error on the last part of the code (the compound field matching):

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.Data = s.B01 
FROM tblWorking t 
INNER JOIN tmpImport_Data s 
ON t.Key = (s.[PTotal_ID] & s.[PComp_ID] & s.[PCat_ID] & s.[PItem_ID] & s.[Geog_ID] & 
s.[Mkt_ID] & s.[Fact_ID] & 'B01');
```

Any help would be appreciated! I hope this is all formatted properly - this is my first question on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after more browsing and several more failed attempts I managed to crack it!
As you can see I haven't changed the actual content of the query just the order of the INNER JOIN and SET!

```
UPDATE tblWorking t 
INNER JOIN tmpImport_Data s 
ON t.Key = (s.PTotal_ID & s.PComp_ID & s.PCat_ID & s.PItem_ID & 
s.Geog_ID & s.Mkt_ID & s.Fact_ID &'B01') SET t.Data = s.B01;
```